# Deleting my message in others' inbox

Tags: email

How can I delete a message I've sent to a friend? Can I delete at the same time in  mine and in my friends inbox?

Comment: By "google" are you referring to "Gmail"?

Comment: Email is not Snapchat...

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible. You can not delete message from others inbox unless you have that user's login credentials.

Once email is sent, you lose all control over it.

Answer (score 1):

In Gmail, this is not possible unless you have already enabled the Undo Send feature.  The official support information about how to do this is [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1284885?hl=en).

Even so, you have a maximum of 30 seconds (10 second by default, but you can choose up to 30) to recall the message.   After that, it is sent and you cannot recall it.

Comment: Even _enabling the Undo Send feature_ will not help in deleting message from others inbox. This option does is _delay_ sending the message for up to a maximum of 30 seconds. During that time, sender can cancel or “undo” the send.